# How to Display data in tables in View in MVC...Ajax and Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. Started learning 2 months back...Here is my Doubt.
I know two approaches to display data in View of MVC(displaying data using Tables) but I am confused which one to use.

Requirement : View should display data from Database using Tables in View.

Approach 1: Fetch data from Database in Controller then fill Model and pass it to View.Loop through Model build Table and Data and Display data.

Approach 2: Define a Table in View.When user clicks button to display data in View, in js(Javascript File) make an ajax call to Controller to get data from Database and build the Table data(using html) in js(Javascript File) and append to the Table in the View.

Code for Approach 1 (this is just example to convey my doubt exactly):

```
public class TableInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; } //you might want to change this to DateTime
    possibly?
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

List<TableInfo> tables = dtTemplates.Rows.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => new TableInfo
        {
            FileName = row["FileName"],
            Date = row["Date"],
            Time = row["Time"],
            Info = row["Info"]
        })
    .ToList();

    close_Connection();
    return View(tables);


@model List<TableInfo>

if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Info</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (TableInfo item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FileName</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.Time</td>
                <td>@item.Info</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Code for Approach 2(Below code is from .js(JavaScript) file):

```
controlSystem = {
        GetContactRequests: function (view) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + "ControlSystemAdmin/GetContactRequests",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'stateFilter': view }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, res) {
                            var items = controlSystem.PopulateControlRequest(res.Data);
                            $("table.control-system tr:last").after(items);
                            $("div.high").tooltip({ content: tooltip });
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (x, status, error) {
                    Common.UI.HandleExceptions(x);
                }
            });
        },

    PopulateControlRequest: function (shiftLifts) {
            var list = [];
            if (shiftLifts) {
                list.push('<tr id=' + shiftLifts.TaskID + '>');
                var qTime = controlSystem.ProcessTime(shiftLifts.QTime);
                list.push('<td><time>' + qTime.date + "&nbsp;" + qTime.time + '</time></td>');
                list.push('<td><div><span>' + ((shiftLifts.AssignedOperator) ? shiftLifts.AssignedOperator : '-') + '</span></div></td>');
                list.push('<td><div>');
                list.push('</div></td>');
                list.push('</tr>');
            }

            return list.length > 0 ? list.join('') : list;
        },
```

Both approaches will do the Job but

1.Which is the best Approach to use? and why?

2.Which is recommended way to do?

3.In Jquery we can build the table fast so browser will be more responsive(which is Approach 2).If we build the table in View(Approach 1) browser may be less responsive so Is Approach 2 better than Approach 1?

4.What are the advantages of one over the other?

5.Please give me detailed explanation,recommend approach,pros and cons of each approach.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So in option 2, the browser makes a request to a server which sends a view back, but then, oops, the server forgot to send the right data, so te browser make another request back to the server to get the right data?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you completely. But in Approach 2 Ajax call will fetch the data from Controller and append the data to the Table in the View.Below is the code for that                                               $("table.control-system tr:last").after(items);

Comment: What I mean is your option 2 is making 2 requests to get the data you need instead of one (why in the world would you want to do that)

Comment: Approach 2 -- show your view page to the user quickly, then you show a loading icon, make a ajax call get a json data and build the table structure, append this table into the view, remove loading icon..
only difference is the amout of data passed from controller to view, If you are passing a HTML back (Approach 1) the data transfer is more compared to Approach 2 where you transfer a string (Json) back.. This is quick..

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can see that only once call is made to get the data...If I am wrong please point the code where I am making call twice...PopulateControlRequest is the function called from GetContactRequests to build the table with data passed.

Comment: In order to get the initial call, you make a request to the controller which returns the view. Then your ajax makes **another** call to the server to get the extra data (which you could have included in the view in the first place!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke In View when I click on LoadData button I am not calling controller...instead call will be made from Ajax call in .js file to fetch data from Controller and append it to the table in View. so there is only one call.....

Comment: OMG. An ajax call is a call to a controller. In option 1 your are making **one** request. In option 2 your are making **two** requests!

Comment: @StephenMuecke :) enjoyy!!